# How can I display HashMap constructed by JSON?

Tags: json, struts2

I know I can display an ArrayList by using

```
for(i=0;i<data.list.length;i++){
    html += data.list[i] +"<br />";
}
```

to display the AarryList Object, I tried the same with HashMap object but it simply doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `HashMap` is converted to an object when serialized to JSON. You can iterate over keys/values using:

```
for (i in data.map) {
  html += data.map[i] + "<br />";
}
```